# SQL Server clustered index with part key

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

What is the SQL for having a primary key consisting of 4 columns but only include 3 of these columns in a clustered index?

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server Management Studio as well?

Comment: Curious, why do you want that?

Comment: Because one of the fields only serves to make rows unique and will only make the index larger than it needs to be.

Comment: If it a very wide column, yes, it makes sense. You do know that the CI will be appended with a hidden (4-byte) column where needed, don't you?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to define two separate things:

1. a **non-clustered primary key** on your four columns

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
   PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
   ```
2. a separate **clustering index** on three of your four columns:

   ```
   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_YourTable
   ON dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col3, Col4)  
   -- adapt this to use those three columns you want
   ```

And yes - of course you can execute those T-SQL scripts in your SQL Server Management Studio :-)

**Update:** to do this in the GUI using clicky-mousy-GUI-tools, you need to do these steps:

1. in Object Explorer, on your table, you need to **first** define the clustered index by going to `Indexes > New Index > Clustered Index` - give it a name and add the columns you want
2. after you've done this, **then** you can define your primary key in the usual table designer view, and since there already is a clustered index, it will become a nonclustered primary key

I haven't found any other way - if you create the primary key first, it becomes a clustered primary key, and I found no way to change that after it's been created

Comment: Thanks, I meant in the gui

Comment: @MikeAlike234 Maybe you should learn to not use the GUI

Comment: Of Course, I what to know both ways

Comment: Of course the clustered index essentially contains the rest of the columns too, so having it be "skinnier" is kind of misleading...

Comment: Thanks good point, but it should be faster when it has one field less to worry about sorting.

Comment: @MikeAlike234 Do you think this "should be faster" is worth maintaining a completely separate and almost wholly redundant index with the additional column?

Comment: You must have misunderstood, the table is supposed to have only one index and that index should be as small and fast as possible to update and insert rows into.

Comment: @MikeAlike234 From your question, sounds like you want a primary key with four columns *and* a clustered index with three columns. The answer you accepted also proposes creating a primary key with four columns *and* a clustered index with three columns. That's two indexes (a primary key is an index, whether it's clustered or not).

Comment: So it's not possible to have only one index if not all keys are included in that index?

Comment: @MikeAlike234 If you need to enforce uniqueness of a column, that column needs to be a key column in *an* index. (PK and unique constraints are implemented under the covers as indexes.) So I'm not sure how you could get away with having a column be a key but not be in an index.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Putting points on the comments, 
what is it good for, except to show that there is much nerds in here?

Comment: @MikeAlike234 It's mostly just to show that they weren't the only person with that opinion - easier to +1 a comment than say "I agree with what so-and-so said" especially if there is nothing further to add. We don't need a bunch of <aol>me toos</aol> cluttering the comments.

Comment: What purpose does it serve to say I agree? Does it help answering the question? Should I use a solution over Another just because it has more votes? Doesen't serve any purpose at all.

Comment: @MikeAlike234: [There's actually a place](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for meta-questions like that, if you are really interested.

Comment: I'm not, I'm just amazed what pointless things some people think give meaning to their lives.